# Pay Additional Dwelling Supplement if buying a new main residence?

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law

This applies to purchasing a home in the UK:

If I were to buy a new house that will become my new permanent residence, but I don't sell my current home and instead intend to let it out, do I need to pay the additional dwelling supplement as part of the stamp duty on either my new home or my old home?

I have lived in the current home for 4 years, if that is important...